# App crashes if closing a dialog while Async Operations are still underway

Tags: c++, asynchronous, winapi

Firstly I'm not familiar with using Async, so the below approach could be completely wrong.
I'm currently decoding multiple images and displaying them in a dialog window.

This works fine, as long as I don't attempt to close the dialog while the decodes are still running.

If I do close the dialog, I get a Debug Assertion Error at `return hh;`

In my class header I have:

```
class CmytestDlg: public CDialog
{

protected:
    // Generated message map functions
    BOOL OnInitDialog() override;
    std::future<HBITMAP> futurebmps[12];

};
```

In the .cpp:

```
BOOL CmytestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    int totalJobs = 12;

    // Queue up all the items,
    for (int i = 0; i < totalJobs; i++)
    {
        futurebmps[i] = std::async(std::launch::async,
            [this](const int i, const std::string& name) {

        // This line is just here to simulate a long running image decode
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

        HBITMAP hh = nullptr;
        PostMessage(8888, i, 0); // Send a message to display the image
        return hh; // <<< Debug Assertion Error Here (If I close dialog to soon)
    
        }, i, std::to_string(0));
        
}
```

The message to draw the image is handled by `OnRefreshAsyncView`:

```
LRESULT CmytestDlg::OnRefreshAsyncView(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // For the purpose of a minimal demo, even if this is empty It still casuses the issue.
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that the issue is triggered by the call to PostMessage, if I comment out this line, I no longer get the crash.

How do I safely handle the scenario where the dialog is closing? So I can prevent this crash.

Comment: What is `futurebmps`?  What are `futures` and `readyFutures` for, since you're not using them for anything.  What is `rr`?  Please post a [mre] so that we can compile and test your code.

Comment: Your lambda captures `this`.  When does that pointer become a dangling pointer?  When does `rr` get destroyed?

Comment: @PaulSanders, sorry `futures` and `readyFutures` were left overs, I've cleaned up the code.

Comment: @DrewDormann, I'm guessing when the dialog closes, but I don't know how to handle this scenario. What is the correct approach to handle this?

Comment: @DrewDormann `rr` is detroyed in the class destructor

Comment: I've updated my question, with a simplified reproducible example

Comment: Please read carefully what a [mre] is.  The code here does _not_ reproduce the runtime issue you describe.  Without a `main` function, [this code can not run at all](https://godbolt.org/z/qq6jbvdx6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that your ATL/MFC program is asserting on the PostMessage call because the window handle became invalid after after you closed/destroyed it.  Somewhere in the middle of that PostMessage call is an ASSERT that the `m_hWnd` instance is non-null.  Hence, the assert is calling attention to a real bug in your code.

PostMessage is is a wrapper for the Win32 API: [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea)  And when you invoke the wrapper function on a different thread, it's likely asserts that `m_hWnd` (or similar HWND member) is non-null.

Consider writing additional (thread safe) code (with a mutex)  that prevents PostMessage from getting called at the same time or after WM_CLOSE/WM_DESTROY is getting processed on the handle.

Something like this:

```
void CmytestDlg::SafePostMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
    if (_isHwndValid)
    {
        PostMessage(uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void CmytestDlg::OnClose(...)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
    _isHwndValid = false;
}
```

Where OnClose is your handler for a WM_CLOSE message and `isHwndValid` is a bool member of your class that gets set to true when the window is created.  And `_mutex` is a std::mutex.

Comment: Thanks, I beleive you are correct, I can see from extra debug logs that my dialog has closed and the destructor has also been called. So I can see how the PostMessage would fail. This is my first try at getting something working with Async and futures. I'll try your suggestions and will report back.

Comment: I'm getting error: `Cannot determine which instance of function template "std::lock" is intended`

Comment: You need to replace `std::lock` with `std::unique_lock`.

Comment: @Chronial, Thanks replacing `std::lock` with `std::unique_lock` has worked, this does address the main crash issue. But I notice that the async threads continue to run until completion. Is there any way to cancel the async/futures? so the application can actually exit immediately.

Comment: @user20716902 - When you schedule work on a thread, you'll need to have a way to signal to the thread to "check for cancellation" and possibly some way for the thread to wake-up to have an application exit scenario. There's no free lunch. For starters, have each work item check some context structure passed for a "need to exit" flag set by the main thread when it starts. Then consider ways the thread can poll for this condition as it does long running work.

Answer (score 2):

To extend [selbie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75349067/758345):

If you want your threads to stop early, you can turn the flag into a std::atomic and check it regularly during your computations, like:

```cpp
std::mutex _mutex;
std::atomic<bool> _shutdown = false;

void CmytestDlg::LongRunningThing()
{
   do_something();
   if (_shutdown) return;
   do_something_else()
   if (_shutdown) return;
   ...
}

void CmytestDlg::SafePostMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
    if (!_shutdown)
    {
        PostMessage(uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void CmytestDlg::OnClose(...)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
    _shutdown = false;
}
```